# Ignoring whitespace in code and pre tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some issues regarding whitespace in my HTML code. This is what is currently looks like:

```
        <pre>
        <code>
             -(void)respring {
               system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
             }
        </code>
        </pre>
```

The indentation marks are to format my HTML a little better, make it more readable. When I save it and upload it to my server, I get 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrC4Q.png). I have already tried using the white-space CSS property to try to fix the issue, but all it does it mess up my codes formatting. I also looked at the JavaScript solutions to this problem via Google but they don't seem to work. I am using highlight js for syntax highlighting if that helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a pre tag is to preserve the spacing that's displayed, including anything at the beginning of a line. This should fix it.

```
        <code>-(void)respring {
  system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
}</code>
```

It may not look pretty in code, but on the page it'll look just fine.